# How to load document instead of string in Stanford's Stanza (StanfordNLP)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-stanza

I'm using Stanford's Stanza, but I can't find any documentation on how to load a document instead of a string.

For instance, for a string it works like this:

```
nlp_pos = stanza.Pipeline('it',processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
doc = nlp_pos("hello how are you")
```

For a document, I thought it would be like:

```
nlp_pos = stanza.Pipeline('it',processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
filename = "example.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
doc = f.read()
```

But it doesn't work. What is an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, lightly adapted from the Stanza documentation. I created a file handle which I passed to the doc = nlp(....). Caution: I am not writing to the original file (Stanza_No_Tags.txt), but to a new file (Stanza_Tokenized.txt). YMMV.

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='zh', processors='tokenize')
Stanza_doc_open = open('Stanza_No_Tags.txt', 'r').read()

doc = nlp(Stanza_doc_open)
for i, sentence in doc.sentences:
    print(f'====== Sentence {i+1} =======', file=open('Stanza_Tokenized.txt', 'a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

@fpohlmann's answer should do, but doesn't close the file handle.

With minimal edits to your original code snippet, one could process a file by

```py
nlp_pos = stanza.Pipeline('it',processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
filename = "example.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    doc = nlp_pos(f.read())
```

And access annotation information the same way as you would the `doc` object from processing the string. Effectively this snippet just reads the entire content of that file into a string, and passes it into Stanza.